# How can I install sudo without using su?

Tags: 18.04, sudo, su, administrator

I need to use sudo but when I try to use it, a prompt tells me the command is not found and I need to install sudo.
So when I switch to su so I can gain root access to install sudo, it says auth failure

[image: sudo and su problem description]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You might need to enter the recovery mode at the Grub menu, select the 'root shell', and try installing sudo. Not sure will work though. Obviously, sudo is preinstalled by default, and removing it was a bad idea.

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/333061/140314

Comment: It's ironic how it suggests to use `sudo` to install `sudo`. Even more ironic that it would probably suggest the same thing again if you actually typed the command it had suggested to you.

Answer (score 12):

Boot up the machine, and after the BIOS screen, hold down the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. You will then be prompted by a menu that looks something like this:

[image: Grub Menu]

If instead you get options like:
[image: Initial Grub Menu]

You need to go to **Advanced Options** using arrow keys and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then choose the **recovery mode**

Hit the down arrow until you select the **2nd entry from the top** (the one with the **recovery mode** in the description) and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now you should see this menu:
[image: Recovery mode]

Using the arrow keys scroll down to network and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to enable networking. If asked to remount the partition, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> on yes.

And then go to root in the same menu and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You should now see a root prompt, something like this:

```
root@gijs-pc:~#
```

At this stage you might have a read-only filesystem. You have to remount it with write permissions:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

now, install `sudo` by:

```
apt install sudo
```

check your sudo settings once again by:

```
visudo
```

also, check if your account `gijs` is a member of sudo
If not, add him as a member of sudo and wheel group by:

```
usermod -aG sudo gijs
usermod -aG wheel gijs
```

Now, you may restart and you now should have access to sudo.

This answer is abridged version of [Jorge Castro's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/740708) on [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/q/24006/740708)

Comment: Maybe you should enable network before dropping to root shell !!

Comment: Hmm..  Indeed as @Olorin said, It is a duplicate. Surely, we can use pkexec too